# TypeError: Cannot call method 'checkId' of undefined because of null prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am facing a `Cannot call method 'checkId' of undefined` in one `node.js` module, but not in another, when calling:

```
res = EntityCommons.prototype.checkId(res,json[RE_FIELD_ID]);
```

I have 3 `node.js` modules `Host`, `Request` and `EntityCommons` in the same directory. `Host` and `Request` require `EntityCommons` as following:

For `Request`:

```
var EntityCommons = require("./EntityCommons.js");

console.log("XXEntityCommons null or undefined : " +
    _.isNullOrUndefined(EntityCommons));
console.log("XXEntityCommons prototype null/und: " +
    _.isNullOrUndefined(EntityCommons.prototype));
```

For `Host`:

```
var EntityCommons = require("./EntityCommons.js");

console.log("EntityCommons null or undefined : " +
    _.isNullOrUndefined(EntityCommons));
console.log("EntityCommons prototype null/und: " +
    _.isNullOrUndefined(EntityCommons.prototype));
```

When I checked the output, I get:

```
EntityCommons null or undefined : false
EntityCommons prototype null/und: true
XXEntityCommons null or undefined : false
XXEntityCommons prototype null/und: false
```

In `Host`, the prototype of `EntityCommons` is `null`. This does not make sense. What could cause this issue?

**Update**

`EntityCommons` requires `Host` too as following:

```
var Host = require("./Host.js");
```

Is this a cyclic issue?

Comment: Is this a cyclic issue? Yes. This http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles paragraph explain why

Answer (score 0):

I solved the cyclic issue using the recommendation available [here](https://coderwall.com/p/myzvmg/circular-dependencies-in-node-js).

In other words, I started by exporting a function at the top of my module:

```
function EntityCommons() { }

module.exports = EntityCommons;
```

It also works with an object:

```
var EntityCommons = {};

module.exports = EntityCommons;
```